# Ｉwant to pack a python tkinter GUI to a EXE file expecting runing on Windows by using pyinstaller, but always get error info like this

Tags: python-3.x

### I've written code in python tkinter and pack it to EXE file using pyinstaller,but at the buttom of the commandline window I got the wrong error message :(background: windows 7, python3.7, pyinstaller 3.5 dev0+)

I'm pretty sure pywin32 has already installed in my comuter,

Comment: cal\programs\python\python37-32\lib\sit
e-packages\pyinstaller-3.5.dev0+8c27d2668c-py3.7.egg\PyInstaller\building\api.py
", line 529, in assemble
    icon.CopyIcons(tmpnm, self.icon)
  File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\sit
e-packages\pyinstaller-3.5.dev0+8c27d2668c-py3.7.egg\PyInstaller\utils\win32\ico
n.py", line 232, in CopyIcons
    except win32api.error as W32E:
AttributeError: module 'win32ctypes.pywin32.win32api' has no attribute 'error'

Comment: Not enough information about the problem. Provide full error message and the code that may be wrong according to it. Also add command you use to create `.exe`. I suppose it may contain mistakes in arguments.